# How to interpret factor analysis transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, factor-analysis

In the following discussion on Stack Overflow, [How to create factors from factanal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4145400/420055) (see answer from @Joris), what is the interpretation of the $F=ML$ transformation, where $M$ is the original data matrix, and $L$ is the loadings matrix? Should it not be $L^{-1}$?